# Easiest way to remotely access a mac mini from windows 8

Tags: windows, macos

I am looking for the easiest way to access a mac mini at my work with a database and applications located at my work from my windows 8 computer at home. I was just wondering how this is done?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a developer centric Q&A site. This question is offtopic. I flagged it to have it moved to a more appropriate site, [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VNC. It is platform-independent.